# Ensure process closure

Tags: c++, c, windows

I have a program that absolutely needs to be able to shut itself down succesfully every single time it needs to.

But I do not know exactly how to go about this.

It runs in user-mode and, while I do not know for sure how to do it, someone may be able to prevent it from closing from kernel-mode, and I'd like to somehow prevent that from happening.

Is there some function I can call or a certain part of the memory I can overwrite that could ensure my process exits?

Of course nothing is fool-proof, but I'd like to know the best way you know of doing this.

Comment: Calling `exit(1)` should do the trick, and if you cannot trust the operating system you're running on, you're going to have a challenge.  Maybe `while (1) exit(1);` ?  This may not stop the program from exiting, but it will stop it from doing anything useful. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My program implements certain protections. I can more or less prevent someone from hooking my functions from user-mode, but if it cannot exit, it must not continue running. And yeah, it's going to be a challege, but this absolutely needs to be implemented and cannot be overlooked by myself

Comment: "someone may be able to prevent it from closing from kernel-mode" if a hacker has kernel access to your system, you're screwed anyway

Comment: Well nowadays almost anyone can do that since there's publicly available kernel driver manual mappers based off different vulnerable drivers or self-signed ones online, so I can just call it quits.

Comment: What are you trying to protect? Memory used by code? Memory used by data? Even if you can trust the underlying operating system, I believe this is unsolvable with a single process because some other admin process can just suspend execution and do whatever it wants.

Comment: Let me ask this directly: what *threats* are you concerned about? "Somebody will read my program code"? "Somebody will read secrets in memory"?  Something else?

Comment: The threat is simply the program still running after it was supposed to exit and not being protected anymore therefore. I am not concerned about memory, so someone suspending it is fine, just do not run it without me knowing and I will not know if my exitprocess/exit is circumvented

Comment: Building in an emergency shutdown volatile variable that you can set to `true` when you want to exit, have every meaningful thread test for it and exit, then in the main thread just call `ExitNow = true; while (1) ExitProcess(1);` is probably the best you can do.

Comment: Question: Why volatile? I found very confusing and contrary info about it online.

Comment: `volatile` so a thread will assume the value can change from some *other* thread.  I'm not sure it's necessary, but it's an old habit.

Comment: `volatile` is often necessary but not sufficient.  You still may have threads running on other cores/cpu's that may have a cached copy of the storage address. `volatile` just tells the compiler what optimizations it should not use.

Comment: You really can't prevent someone with kernel mode access, from replacing your exit function and any of your internal variables.  The trick is to just make it cheaper and easier to pay the license fees.  Perhaps your business model is to blame for these concerns?

Comment: Call TerminateProcess().  If that does not work, you're screwed:(  Don't bother with volatile flags and the like, just call that API.

Comment: @SteveFriedl [Is volatile useful with threads in C++](http://isvolatileusefulwiththreads.in/C++/) ;-) I would use an `atomic` instead.

Comment: @Scheff that won't work reliably either.  Threads looping, (either internally while not polling the atomic, or externally in some library), or blocked, (on I/O or inter-thread comms), will not be stopped by such a mechanism.

Comment: With most apps, libraries, DLLs, ExitProcess() is sufficient, but if you need to be sure of immediate process termination, there is only one cboice.

Comment: @MartinJames I surely consider your advice as the better approach. However, the recommendation of `volatile` for inter-thread communication seemed to me worth a note.

Comment: Well, 'volatile' was really designed for comms with interrupt handlers.  Inter-thread comms is safer handled with atomics, (as suggested by others), and events, semaphores an other such kernel signaling.

Comment: You simply can not protect a user mode process against attacks from kernel mode. You might like to zero out all data space and/or let it crash. But any decent attacker will patch that part and go on.

Comment: @Scheff - I'm old school and have used `volatile` for decades; I suppose I should look into newer mechanisms

Comment: @Scheff - ok, yah, reading about `volatile` vs `atomic` is clear that I needed to catch up; appreciate the nudge.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the extensive commentary:

- It's not possible to guarantee *any* kind of user-mode behavior if you cannot trust the underlying operating system; this is just not how the world works.
- Any outside program with admin rights can run a debugger on your code to pause it, where it can inspect memory and steal secrets, change program code, or even inject a new thread (on Windows, at least) to run and keep an eye on things while your "real" code runs. This is a very hostile environment to work in.
- You said you were not worried about secrets being stolen, which was very helpful, so the best thing you can do when you decide to stop is to just call the OS primitive that gets the process to exit.  `ExitProcess()` for exiting the current program, or `TerminateProcess()` when called on your own handle. If these are not sure kills, there's almost nothing else you can do.

My suggestion of a volatile/atomic variable was more along the lines of a ridiculous response to a preposterous premise: if you believe that `ExitProcess` might have been hooked to be a no-op, then you could put that call in a loop so the main code won't do any real work even if it does stay around in memory.

```
// this is ridiculous
#include <atomic> // hat tip to @Scheff

extern atomic_bool shouldShutdown = false;

void checkShutdown(void)
{
   // looping in case unicorns have hooked the OS
   while (shouldShutdown) ExitProcess(1);
}
```

Call `checkShutdown()` at the top of each thread's main loop so it will at least stop doing real work.

However: Though I enjoy thinking out loud about interesting problems, this is a fully ridiculous solution: if `ExitProcess` doesn't work, you're against an adversary who wants it more than you do, and I concur with @jwdonahue in suggesting that this is a business-model problem and not a technical one.

**EDIT** Having some fun thinking about this, the `checkShutdown()` could not only loop on checking the variable, but do it *recursively* to blow out the stack, meaning a sure eventual kill from all the threads.

Almost feels like code golf :-)

Also, I can't believe I'm still thinking about this, we really need to use `TerminateProcess` in this context rather than `ExitProcess` because the latter's declaration is decorated with `__declspec(noreturn)` in `<winnt.h>`, the compiler knows that code beyond it is unreachable, so it's possible that some of our crazy shenanigans could be optimized out.

```
void checkShutdown(void)
{
    while (shouldShutdown) {
        TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 1);
        checkShutdown();
    }
}
```

It's probably not out of the question that this recursive call could be optimized to an iterative one - it's not quite tail recursive, but close - but I'm not going to look in that much detail to sort it out.